Using FindStr in a batch file to change a directory path in several files
I need to change out a path in a file to the current path I'm using to run the batch file.
Heres a string example in a file:
<Image>C:\Users\abcdir\OneDrive - Enc\3322 \Operations\BrightSign</Image>
<Video>C:\Users\abcdir\OneDrive - Enc\3322 \Operations\BrightSign</Video>

Lets say the current directory path is C:\Users\defdir\OneDrive - Enc, what I need to end up with is:
<Image>C:\Users\defdir\OneDrive - Enc\3322 \Operations\BrightSign</Image>
<Video>C:\Users\defdir\OneDrive - Enc\3322 \Operations\BrightSign</Video>

My thought is to findstr "C:\Users\*\OneDrive" and replace the * with the current path C:\Users\defdir\OneDrive
FOR doesnt like special characters such as <>:\, and these files are full of them.
Do I nest the FindStr in a For loop to have it look though the folder and its sub folder for these files? Speed isn't really an issue, (there are less than twenty files in total), and if I use an extension in the file search it reduces to around half that.
I'm just not sure how to build this loop, and need guidance.
EDIT:
It was late and I was pretty vague in my question. Here's the full scoop.
We use BrightSign players that create and Schedule file and a Config file.
The issue is in these files, the file path to all the assets has the PC's path it was created on. So, if Larry creates a config file, Curly or Moe cant open it on their PC's because the path has Larrys PC as the path name, even though everyone pulls from the same Folders on a OneDrive.
The idea is to make a batch file that anyone can run first. Its job is to get the current path (C:\Users\Larry\OneDrive.....
Then look through the Folder for all config files. Search for paths that always start with C:\Users, then an unknown user (Larry , Curly, Moe, etc), followed by OneDrive......
Then change out the user to the current User, then save. Now that user can open all the files to edit them.

Surely you have not really named a directory with a trailing space character, \3322 \. Also what if the users current directory is not where you are expetcting? they can run a batch file from any directory. It sounds like the batch file directory, %~dp0, would be more use to you, or possibly even the variable %OneDriveCommercial%.

Your question body mentions that you are searching for files, not changing the username in a text file location. Please provide more information about the true task.

It was late and I was pretty vague in my question. Heres the full scoop.

So, you really want to substitute either %OneDriveCommercial% as already mentioned, %OneDriveConsumer%, or %OneDrive%. You could probably get that like this: @Set "ODrv=" & For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%G In ('(Set OneDrive^) 2^>NUL') Do @If Exist "%%H\3322 \Operations\BrightSign" Set "ODrv=%%H\3322 \Operations\BrightSign". Then If Not Defined ODrv Exit /B. Your next lines would follow these two, for actually changing the file contents. Please note however my earlier comment, only a fool has file or directory names ending with a trailing whitespace character, (\3322 \).

I dont make the directories. I just have to work with what some admin made.  I'll try the @if Exist cmd and see what I get. Thanks

the started program should awready inherit the current directory by default when you start it like this:
start "" "C:\Users\abcdir\OneDrive - Enc\3322 \Operations\BrightSign"

you can also see the property "Start in" in windows shortcuts that does the same

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

:: get username from current directoryname as `dest`

FOR /f "tokens=3delims=\" %%u IN ("%cd%") DO SET "dest=%%u"

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("u:\your files\t w o\q78431108.txt") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3*delims=\" %%g IN ("%%e") DO (
  IF "%%j" equ "" (
   echo %%g
  ) else (
   ECHO %%g\%%h\%dest%\%%j
  )
 )
)
)>"u:\your files\t w o\q78431108_2.txt"

GOTO :EOF

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.
Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both usebackq and the quotes around the filename can be  omitted.
I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.
I used a file named q78431108.txt containing your data for my testing.
First, use for /f to select the third string of the current directory name using backslash as delimiter, which is the destination username
C:\Users\defdir
-1 ----2 -----3

Then read each line from the file (delims=) to %%e
And tokenise on backslash, selecting tokens 1,2,3 and "the remainder"
<Image>C:\Users\abcdir\OneDrive - Enc\3322 \Operations\BrightSign</Image>
------%%g --%%h ---%%i -----------------------------------------------%%j

then echo with the backslashes reinserted and substitute for the username with %dest%
The
(
 for....(
 )
)>filename

syntax will redirect the echoed output to a new file, filename
Note: whereas dest is the variable name I chose for the username, it can be virtually any variablename. BUT username is a variable set by the system (current username) so username, whilst logical, should not be used.

This is VERY close to the solution. Not every line in the file is a path that I need to change. Some are settings like
False</

for these I just need to pass the string without mods. Do I nest another FOR to look for "OneDrive" , make the mods to the path, and if OneDrive is not there, just pass the string?
Thanks!

Always best to provide proper representative data - saves revisions
